# Ripple effect in the useState when I try to use it to store an element in an Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Background**

I am trying to do this challenge (please refer to the screenshot below) where I have to replicate the Kanban Board. [Here is the link to the challenge](https://www.frontendmentor.io/challenges/kanban-task-management-web-app-wgQLt-HlbB)

[image]

But I am stuck.
First off, here is what I mean by the Ripple Effect:

In the modal under the columns section, I want to store each entry in the input into an array that is managed by useState(). However, when I do so, each letter of the array gets stored separately.

[image]

Here is the code for the form that I have embedded in a modal. I am not using Context:

```
import { useState } from "react";

// importing styles
import "../styles/Modal.css";

const NewBoardForm = ({
  setTabs,
  modalHandler,
  tabs,
  handleTabs,
  handleBoardColumns,
}) => {
  const [allColumns, setAllColumns] = useState([]);
  const [name, setName] = useState([]);
  const [board, setBoard] = useState("");

  // the function that adds column inside the sidebar form
  const addColumn = (event) => {
    setAllColumns([
      ...allColumns,
      <input
        className="columnsInput"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setName((old) => {
            return [...old, e.target.value];
          });
        }}
        type="text"
      />,
    ]);
    console.log(name);
  };

  const formReset = () => {
    setAllColumns([]);
    setName([]);
    setBoard("");
  };

  // get the data from the form

  const getData = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const tabsInput = {
      title: board,
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1,
    };

    const boardColumns = {
      title: name,
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1,
    };

    console.log(name);

    handleBoardColumns(boardColumns);

    console.log(board);

    handleTabs(tabsInput);

    modalHandler();
    formReset();
  };

  return (
    // form starts from here
    <>
      <form className="boardForm">
        <label>
          <span className="name"> Board Name</span>
          <input
            className="nameInput"
            type="text"
            onChange={(e) => setBoard(e.target.value)}
          />
        </label>

        {/* new section for columns */}

        <span className="columns">Columns</span>
        {allColumns.map((column) => {
          return <label className="addNewColumn">{column}</label>;
        })}

        <button
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            addColumn();
          }}
          className="addColumnBtn"
          type="button"
        >
          + Add Column
        </button>

        {/* section for columns ends here */}

        <button className="close-btn" onClick={getData} type="submit">
          Create New Board
        </button>
      </form>

      {/* form ends here */}
    </>
  );
};

export default NewBoardForm;
```

**Here is the link to the Github Repo:**

[GitHub Repository](https://github.com/kowais915/task_management_app)